# Why ethernet network icon and basic connectivity change

Tags: networking, wireless

For the past three months, since covid slowed down internet connectivity on Jio in India, my Ubuntu internet connectivity has become erratic.  On Ubuntu 18.04 in the early morning before 6 AM when I tether an Android phone to my laptop the internet connectivity indicator in the upper right-hand corner of the desktop shows the normal three boxes in a triangle and has good speed.  As network traffic increases the indicator turns to three gray boxes with a question mark in the middle and connectivity speed remains decent for a few websites, such as YouTube, Google Search and a few others, but connectivity stops for most websites.  Chromium, Vivaldi and Firefox browsers show the following error for such sites: “This site can’t be reached. askubuntu.com’s server IP address could not be found.”

Oddly, in dual-booted Win 10 all websites open reliably 24/7, though sometimes at slow speeds.  In Fedora on the same hardware the behavior is identical to Ubuntu.  I’ve tried changing the DNS settings in Ubuntu to use Cloud Flare, Google and even the DNS settings in Windows, but to no avail.

My questions are, what’s going on here and is there a way to manually select or retain the working network mode found in the early morning?  Thanks.  BTW, at 5 PM I had to send this post from Win 10. :-(

Comment: do you use Wifi or USB tethering? if Wifi, what drivers, i.e. what does `sudo lshw -class network` say?

Comment: if i understood you correctly, you have a wired connection, that slows down as soon as all the other people wake up and come online? What confuses you is that linux handles the networking differently to windows?

Comment: For those trying to parse this question, Jio is a mobile service provider. OP is using an Android phone to tether his computer and use mobile data. So this is neither WiFi, nor Ethernet.

Comment: This happens to me too. I am using wired connection and when the signal is not good only one of the three boxes (in the icon) is on. Still it carries on, though sometimes connection drops altogether and the icon turns into a ?.  I enable wifi and carry on. A few seconds later wired connection gets going I see that wifi has been turned off.

Comment: Using USB tethering.

Comment: As stated, the question is why Win 10 works and Linuxes don't, and what needs to be done to improve this.

Comment: @user68186 Ubuntu calls this USB tethering an ethernet connection.  As you say, it is not wifi.

Comment: @elmclose  No wifi available here, only tethering via mobile data connection.  During the entire day most sites fail to open in Ubuntu, though they open in Win 10.

Comment: You can file a bug report. Then the developers will ask you to send more details and look into it. Bugs are off-topic here. See [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) for more details.